# How can we change the style of the facegrid edge in SliceDensityPlot3D

Tags: plotting

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 Exp[-2 ((x)^2/(80) + (y)^2/(80))], "BackPlanes", {x, -15, 
  15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -1, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 1]},
      Rescale[#, {0, 1}]] &), Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

I would like to change the edge style, I tried `FaceGridsStyle` but did not work?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the setting for `BoundaryStyle` to `Directive[Green, Thick]`:

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 Exp[-2 ((x)^2/(80) + (y)^2/(80))], "BackPlanes", {x, -15, 
  15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -1, 3}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 1]},
      Rescale[#, {0, 1}]] &), Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

Add the options `FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick]` and `FaceGrids -> {{-1,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {0,0,-1}}` to get

[image]